# Erro Sintaxe SQL ao exportar CREATE TABLE (Myphpadmin)

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

Sou novo por aqui e ainda não iniciei meus estudos em SQL e PHP, mas gostaria de pedir ajuda.

Ao tentar baixar um conteúdo do tema do meu site em WP, aparece msg de erro:

> Cannot export CREATE TABLE sql for rconvert-subscriptions. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-subscriptions' at line 1

Na sintaxe está:

```
SELECT * FROM `wphk_rconvert-subscriptions` WHERE 1
```

Gostaria de saber o que devo corrigir na sintaxe. Será que devo atualizar meu MySQL server?

Answer (score 1):

Olá

A Tabela `wphk_rconvert-subscriptions` não esta criada. Experimente criar a tabela e tentar novamente.

`CREATE TABLE wphk_rconvert-subscriptions`

e passe os campos correspondente.
deve funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema, como o próprio erro diz, está na sintaxe. 
Está faltando a condição para o WHERE. Você deve especificar a coluna em que o WHERE = 1

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM 'wphk_rconvert-subscriptions' WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: Guilherme, quando eu especifico a coluna para o WHERE, aparece a seguinte mensagem: MySQL não retornou nenhum registo .